# Migrations for ExpressionEngine

Tags: database-migrations

Is there an add-on that adds database migrations features ala [Codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/migration.html) or [Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/migrations) for ExpressionEngine?

It is really a pain when making a dev environment and having to recreate it on a production server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The true answer is unfortunately "no". There have been some attempts in this vain by EE addon developers and there may be some "creative" solutions out there but there is not anything that I'm aware of which makes this process easy.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I have seen to something like this is detailed in a blog post: ["Deploying ExpressionEngine based site"](http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Deploying-ExpressionEngine-based-site) by Krasimir Tsonev.

He outlines steps to log all queries in an environment, writing them to files. The queries can then be run, as migrations, by executing the saved queries on your other environment's database. Scroll down to the "Database migration" heading where it says "My way" [(right here)](http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Deploying-ExpressionEngine-based-site#my-way).

I haven't tried it myself, but it looks like a promising approach and there are some good comments.